# K values in Logistic equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I just had a small question regarding the use of $k$ in logistic equations.

I understand that an equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = x(10 - x)$ would become $\frac{dx}{x(10-x)} = dt$ which can then become the partial fractions

$\frac{1}{x(10-x)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{10-x}$

However, if there is a value for $k$ such that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0.2x(10-x)$ would the $0.2$ value be on the denominator of the partial fraction or on the side that equals $dt$? If it part of the partial fraction, how does that change the $A$ and $B$ fractions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you re-write the question? I don't understand,do you need to find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I'm asking where the k value goes